# Xamarin DataGridView Value pass to another Page Textbox

Tags: sql, xamarin.android

i would like to request you that kindly help me how to pass the value from Xamarin DataGridView selected row to another page TextBox. please see the mention below of my code.

**This is my code to fill the DatGridView:**

```
private void Bind_GVhkCL(string text)
        {
            {
                string query = "SELECT Room_No as 'Room No',Room_Status as 'Room Status', S_Time as 'Start Time',E_Time as 'End Time',c_date as 'Create Date'from HK_Chk " + text;
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                GVhkCL.ItemsSource = dt;
                //GVhkCL.RowHeight = 60; 
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }


        }

This is code that I am trying to pass the value to another form or you can give me any other idea:

private void DataGridView_DoubleTap(object sender, DataGridGestureEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item != null)
            {
                var editForm = new EditFormPage(GVhkCL, GVhkCL.GetItem(e.RowHandle),
                                (DataTemplate)Resources["Room No"]);
                Navigation.PushAsync(editForm);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Did you read the official document about [passing data when navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73539826/xamarin-datagridview-value-pass-to-another-page-textbox)?

Comment: Dear Ms. Liyun, yes I read the official documents but I am not successful which is why I post help from you guys. can you please help me I have to finish my college project I have very less days to submit the project.

Comment: Dear Ms. Liyun Please check this link i upload Image what i need and also 2nd link my code i am sure that code not correct  Image Like: https://postimg.cc/K3ZhTnKG   my code: link https://codeshare.io/JbYr3y

Comment: You said that the `Room State` have been passed successfully but the `Room No` not, so please check whether you get the value of `Room No` from the clicked item or not.

Comment: Dear Liyun, no even Room Status also not pass no any value pass this is the issue if one value pass then i can fix the issue but issue is that non of any value pass

Comment: Dear Liyun, no even Room Status also did not pass in the picture i miss the word no, no any value pass this is the issue if one value pass then I can fix the issue but the issue is that non of any value pass

Comment: All right, did you check whether you get the value in the `DataGridView_DoubleTap` or not?

Comment: Dear Ms. Liyun this is the main issue i am not getting values in the DataGridView_DoubleTap

Comment: So you can try to search how to get the data from the selected item at first.

Comment: Dear Liyun you can not help me for code

Comment: Or you can show more code about the data model of the item.

Comment: Dear Ms. Liyun, please see this is my code its working with windows form but its not working with Devexpress DataGridView control int[] selectedRowHandles = grid.GetSelectedRows();
            TBRoomNo.Text = System.Convert.ToString(GVEmployeeProfile.GetRowCellValue(selectedRowHandles[0], "ID"));             This is error code link: https://postimg.cc/7bpPXH6S

Comment: Did you try to convert the sender as a model or a item and then get the data from it?

Comment: Dear Liyun can you please make one example code for me now my mind stop working because since i week i am trying this kind of logic but not been successful.

Comment: i am trying this code but its shows an error 'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'GetSelectedRows' and no accessible extension method 'GetSelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridView' GetSelectedRows this is my full code int[] selectedRowHandles = grid.GetSelectedRows();
            DisplayAlert("Show Record: ", System.Convert.ToString(grid.GetCellValue(selectedRowHandles[0], "Room NO")), "OK");

Comment: Dear Liyun i am waiting for your reply, please.

Comment: I don't know the control in your xaml, can you show the code where use the `DataGridView_DoubleTap` in the xaml?

Comment: Dear Liyun, please see this link for my full code along with C# and XAML as per your request: Link: https://codeshare.io/JbYdzr

Comment: I have never used the DataGridView control, can you get the `grid.SelectedRowHandle()`? In addition, it seems a collection view, where is the item template? According to the image you provided. It likes a listview, you can refer to [getting the data from the selected item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#single-selection).

Comment: dear Liyum as I told you i am using DevExpress Controls please see the link if you can understand  link: https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridView.SelectedRowHandle

Comment: Dear if you can tell me how to get row index number i can fix my problem

Comment: The link said the `grid.SelectedRowHandle()` will return the index of the selected row.